# Is there a way to change Specman's log file through the Specman Console?

Tags: specman

While debugging with Specman i need to change the log file, which is specman.elog in default.
is there a way to change Specman's log file via the console?

Answer (score 1):

BTW, specman log files file extention is *.elog. When you specify a different file extention (LOG_NAME.log) it will override it, and will make it hard for you to identify the specman log from other logs. If you omit the extention, it will defaultively assign .elog extention.

Answer (score 1):

just to clarify - the " is not required

set log part1
(doing some commands)
set log part2
(doing some more commands)

will result with three log files

1. specman.elog
2. part1.elog
3. part2.elog

Answer (score 0):

Changing log file can be done using 'set log "LOG_NAME.log"'